# I need a word to describe the quality of a rectangle that is "upright"

Tags: vocabulary

[image: Rectangles]

I would like a more formal word that describes the rectangle on the left as opposed to the slanted one on the right. For some reason, I can't seem to think of a description without being wordy...

Comment: It's the same *rectangle*, regardless of whether you depict it in *landscape* or *portrait* orientation.

Comment: It's the rectangle which is *tipping over*, it's had one too many.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Or some too few.

Comment: @Drew Oh, dear it's *my* left. Well then the rectangle is *lying down*, it's tired.P.S What's "upright" about it?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: **Horizontal rectangle**, see on Google Images. Also see **vertical rectangle**

Comment: Rectangle on the left: [couchant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couchant). Rectangle on the right: [rampant](http://www2.merriam-webster.com/mw/art/rampant.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that many are now familiar with and understand the page layout orientation standards, landscape and portrait. Thus the rectangle on the left has a landscape orientation. One might also describe the rectangle on the left as having 'the long sides aligned with the horizon' or possibly state it is has an 'orthogonal orientation.'

Comment: Thanks, I think "orthogonal" is the word I was looking for here. A quick search for "orthogonal rectangle" gives me some results from academic types who are using that to designate the shapes I am interested in.